# Is Programming/Coding necessary to pursue a masters degree in robotics?

Tags: programming-languages

I am soon going to finish my undergrad in mechatronics engineering and wish to take up robotics for my masters. But I absolutely dislike any form of coding/programming. I am however,interested in the mathematics and physics behind the working of a robot. I'd also love to study about the control systems in a robot. So is coding a requirement if I want to take up robotics?

PS: I couldn't find the right tag for the question. Sorry! Please direct me to the right one if required.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* MumboJumbo, but I'm afraid that *Life Questions* are off-topic. Questions about choosing how to spend your time (which class to take, what career to pursue, etc.) may be about difficult decisions, & they are often important, but they are too specific to your own situation & are unlikely to help future visitors to the site. They would be better off asked in [chat], when you have [chat privileges](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, see [ask] & [about]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is coding a ***requirement*** if you want to take up robotics? **No**, *but* it is strongly recommended.

The field of robotics is highly multidisciplinary. I primarily work on AUVs as a software developer, but my team consists of mechanical (ME), electrical (EE), and computer (CPE) engineers as well as physicists. Most of them don't look or write any of the code, but rather (as needed) assist the software developers in working out the mathematics for our acoustic systems, motor controllers, etc.

If that sounds like what you are interested in, then those opportunities definitely do exist, but they are slim. Most groups that do work with robotics (industry or academia) expect their members to be able to work directly with code to varying degrees. That could be MEs or physicists programming high-level controllers, EEs or CPEs programming microcontrollers, or working directly on the larger code base (architecture, planning, perception, etc.).

With this in mind, I suggest giving programming another chance. Not everyone will enjoy programming, but I think most people who turn away from it just didn't have a good first experience to really be able to appreciate the beauty of computing.

Answer (score 0):

You can study and practice robotics control without dealing with much programming. Look at mechanical engineering or electrical engineering departments with a degree in control systems. Their programming course requirements will be listed in the curriculum.

You will probably spend some time using MATLAB (simulink), Mathematica, or another similar language for numerical analysis.